# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException when executing queryIntentActivities

Tags: java, android

I am using a device with Android 5.0.1 and when execute the function:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
List<ResolveInfo> apps = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent,0);
```

An exception of type TransactionTooLargeException is thrown ....
I cannot use the flag:  MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY because I can't be limited to  only those activities that support the CATEGORY_DEFAULT.
Looks that the problem is related with the amount of data returned, like many related issues that I found here at stackoverflow ...
Is there a way to break this response? Or is there a query, equivalent, or a combination of flags that allow get the same results making more than one query?
I am asking because is not clear to me the meaning of flag = 0 in documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities(android.content.Intent, int)

May be I can query more than once, with different queries, and combine the results?

Comment: Do you have added data to your intent? this exception is from the ammount of data you put in the Bundle of a Intent (cant exceed 1mb memory, combined with all pending intents of the application)

Answer (score 0):

You could chunk your query by being a bit more specific with how you form your [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), and do multiple queries rather than 1 lump sum query.  Right now, you're querying basically every application (potentially multiple for each) on the device (since everything that can launch will have a android.app.action.Main action), which goes over your allocation of the ~1 MB shared buffer [parcel limit](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles.html#sdbp) causing the exception:

From the docs:

```
{ action=android.app.action.MAIN } matches all of the activities that can be used as top-level entry points into an application.

{ action=android.app.action.MAIN, category=android.app.category.LAUNCHER } is the actual intent used by the Launcher to populate its top-level list.
```

So, adding a category narrows the search results.  If you need everything of action type "android.app.action.Main", use that as the action, then iterate over an additional set of [categories](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_DEFAULT) ex sudo code:

```
List<ResolveInfo> activities = new ArrayList<ResolveInfo>()

String[] categories = new String[] { android.app.category.LAUNCHER, additional... }

for(String category: categories){
   Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
   mainIntent.addCategory(category)
   List<ResolveInfo> matches = manager.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);  //You might want to use a better @ResolveInfoFlag to narrow your ResolveInfo data
   if(!matches.isEmpty()){
      activities.addAll(matches)
   }
}
```

You should also probably do a try catch, because when doing a MATCH_ALL, there's still no guarantee that the query won't be too large.  There might be appropriate flags to help with this, but I'm not familiar with your use case.

Comment: This is a Launcher application. Then I need to search for all Activities even that not specify a category, because this can be blocked by user config (configuration file), even if is not displayed in launcher.

Comment: I don't really understand the "need" to search everything with android.app.action.MAIN only.  This doesn't seem like the correct approach. 
The category android.app.category.LAUNCHER is used for launcher specific entry points, so that should be used in the resolution of what to display for launcher options associated with launcher icons as described above...

Comment: It's possible for one app to declare multiple "android.app.action.MAIN" if the application has multiple top level entry points (maybe you access the app differently from a notification, or different app, etc).  You should only access the application from a launcher icon if it has the "android.app.category.LAUNCHER" category.